# ruby rake utility on the command line

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

So I am very new to Ruby, but I have written a few rake files to get the hang of things, and they worked perfectly well. Fast forward through a vacation, and now I can't get them to run at all, even the most basic rake file that only contains a 'put'

I am only running the rake utility on the command line, in the same directory as my rake file, yet I am dogged by a 'No Rakefile found' error.

My Internet research repeatedly says to make sure you're in your application directory, but as far as I can tell, I have not made an app.

```
C:\Users\me\.rake>rake mytask --trace
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_
load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block
 in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `stan
dard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_
rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block
 in run'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `stan
dard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you *sure* there's a rake file in your `.rake` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your rakefile needs to be named one of these: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb
or you need to pass rake the `-f` flag and specify a file like this:

`rake -f my_awesome_rakefile.rb`

so heres a tutorial:

create a file named **my_awesome_rakefile.rb** and fill it with:

```
task :check_awesomeness do
  puts "still awesome!"
end
```

now run `rake -f my_awesome_rakefile.rb check_awesomeness` from the same directory as my_awesome_rakefile.rb and check if it's still awesome.

or you could rename the file to `rakefile` and rename the task to `default` and just run `rake` by itself.

---

p.s. `man rake` is your friend. and this too: http://rake.rubyforge.org/files/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html .

Comment: This worked for me! Are there any settings or environment variables that would have made this unnecessary? I'm more than happy to use -f [filename], but I could nave sworn I didn't use it originally.